# Does MARIADB support TableSpaces?

Tags: mariadb

Does MARIADB support TableSpaces ? I want to know can I create table spaces in MARIA DB - as they allow to use INNODB .

Comment: How about you try it and let us know?

Comment: short answer No, it doesnt support it

Answer (score 1):

What do you get from `SELECT * FROM information_schema.INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES`?  See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/information-schema-tablespaces-table/ "starting with MariaDB 5.5".  However: "The table is a MariaDB and MySQL extension, and does not include information about InnoDB tablespaces."

Why are you hoping for tablespaces?